# Js appended button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, event-handling, append

On my website you can add cards to your collection. When you have clicked on the plus JS removes the plus button and inserts the minus button. The minus button is now visible but not working. I've read some articles about the new appended button not being clickable because the button didn't exist when the page was first loaded. Hence also when I reload the page the minus is working fine.

here's my code:

HTML

```
echo '<li class="card addcards" id="card_' . $card["id"] . '">';
echo '<div class="status addtocol_btn addtocol_card_'.$card['id'].'" id="'.$card['id'].'"><span id="addtocol_'.$card['id'].'">'.$col_id.'</span>+</div>';
echo '</li>';
```

JS

```
// AJAX ADD CARD TO COLLECTION ON SEARCHPAGE
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".addtocol_btn").click(function(){
        var card_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var col_id = document.getElementById('addtocol_'+card_id).innerHTML;
        $.ajax({
            url: ""+homelink+"/addtocol.php", 
            method: "POST",
            data:{'card_id':card_id, 'col_id':col_id},
            success: function(result){
                $('div[id="' + card_id + '"]').fadeOut();
             $('#card_'+card_id+'').append('<div class="status del_btn del_btn_card_'+card_id+'" id="'+card_id+'"><span id="removefromcol_'+card_id+'">'+col_id+'</span>-</div>');              
        }});
    });
});

// AJAX REMOVE CARD FROM COLLECTION ON SEARCHPAGE
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".del_btn").click(function(){
        var card_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var col_id = document.getElementById('removefromcol_'+card_id).innerHTML;
        //if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this card from your collection?")) {
        $.ajax({
            url: ""+homelink+"/delete_card.php", 
            method: "POST",
            data:{'card_id':card_id, 'col_id':col_id},
            success: function(result){
             $('div[id="' + card_id + '"]').fadeOut();
             $('#card_'+card_id+'').append('<div class="status addtocol_btn addtocol_card_'+card_id+'" id="'+card_id+'"><span id="addtocol_'+card_id+'">'+col_id+'</span>+</div>');
        }});
        //}
    });
});
```

I've checked with the Jquery manual: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ and aplied the there shown code but that just breaks my entire add/remove code:

```
// AJAX ADD CARD TO COLLECTION ON SEARCHPAGE
//$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".card").on("click", "div", function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        var card_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var col_id = document.getElementById('addtocol_'+card_id).innerHTML;
        $.ajax({
            url: ""+homelink+"/addtocol.php", 
            method: "POST",
            data:{'card_id':card_id, 'col_id':col_id},
            success: function(result){
                $('div[id="' + card_id + '"]').fadeOut();
             $('#card_'+card_id+'').append('<div class="status del_btn del_btn_card_'+card_id+'" id="'+card_id+'"><span id="removefromcol_'+card_id+'">'+col_id+'</span>-</div>');              
        }});
    });
//});
```

Who can help me out here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you generate HTML programmatically?

Comment: If you are referring to the examples above? Then yes, that's how my code is at the moment. If you have any suggestions for improvement I would gladly hear them though.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/180501/which-is-better-to-include-html-inside-php-code-or-outside-it points out that templates are the best practise. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The Problem

You can't bind event handlers to non-existent elements (which you are trying to do as you append `delete` button into the DOM).

As the DOM changes though, your handlers can also be lost when elements are removed.

## The Solution

Bind your handlers to the `document` rather than specific selectors and filter for specific elements.

In other words, use this syntax for your handlers:

```
$(document).on("click", ".del_btn", function(){
```

Comment: Thanks! I was getting lost with that event stuff. Glad you pointed me in the right direction. It works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

Though not the best way, but sometimes .live() (now deprecated) also does the trick. Here is how

```
$('.del_btn').live("click", function(){// your code here});
```